# HTML and CSS how to move my logo to the left

Tags: html, css

I want my logo to be at the left side or to use flex-start, but it doesnt move at all?

the html and css are here

https://codepen.io/medovanx/pen/zYERajx

```
header img {
  height:65px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

Comment: you have to set justify-content:flex-start to the link not to the img, because the link is a flex child

Comment: you are mixing flex container and flex children. An IMG doesn't have children, so it doesn't make sense to put `display: flex` on it. You most likely want to target the wrapping container.

Comment: margin-right: auto;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring the header img as the flex-Container. Which means that all of the content in header img will be at the beginning of header img.

header img is inside of header, which itself is a flex-Container that tells all of its children to be `justify-content: flex-end;`.

As a child of header, header img will obey the rules of its parent.

If you want header img to be on the left and the rest on the right, you could wrap all of the header children you want to be on the right side in another div and set justify-content of the header to `justify-content: space-between;`.

That way, all of the direct children of header will be pushed apart as far as possible, since now it only has two children: header img and the newly created div containing everything else. If you now want the contents of the second child to be in a row, you simply give the div a class of `display: flex;`. You don't need to specific row, as that's the default flex-direction.

Here is an example:
[Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/dev-inka/pen/VwMQdVb)

```
div.parent {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

div.child-2 {
    display: flex;
}
```

Comment: this is the best answer I recieved, thank you so much, I now understand how silly it was to set an img as a container for flex hahhahaha

Answer (score 1):

```css
header .github {
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: you have used `.github` on anchor tag of logo. so I have added `margin-right: auto;` css and fix this issue.

Comment: Already working bro. I think you haven't check copepen link properly.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
header .github {
  margin: 0 auto 0 0;
}
```

Comment: this is a nice solution, thank you!